# Searching for Reverse Dependencies on Hackage

Tags: haskell, hackage

Is there a way to search for Hackage packages that depend on package X (for any package X)? It would be great to find examples of how a package is used in the wild to get an idea of its capabilities. (Also useful for [attempting to] resolve cabal hell.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Michael Snoyman's [packdeps](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse). For example, this [link](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/text) will tell you all the package that depend on the package `text`. You can just edit that link with the package name to get the reverse dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Hackage's [**Reverse Dependency Monitor**](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse).